# Percent decoding with ignoring specified chars

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, urlencode

I want to specify what characters should be ignored while percent decoding.

If I have string `some %5D string %5B` and character `]` is specified as not to be decoded, the result of decoding should be `some %5D string [`

It is easy to do when you assume that encoded character will be in `%FF` form but the problem is with characters that encoded form looks like this `%E2%82%AC`

Comment: I usually decode, then reencode, which will only encode the characters I want encoded and not the others.

Comment: I was thinking about that but I stated that maybe there is another and better way.

Comment: There are many ways to solve a rather basic problem like that. I'd need a definition on "better" though